# Google Analytics Status: Tracking Not installed

Tags: google-analytics, wordpress

I set up a website, and below is my main page. As you see I have added the tracking code, but when I login to google analytics, I see Google Analytics Status: Tracking Not installed. If you think there are no mistakes in below codes, how can I debug to find the problem ?

```
 <!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
        <title>
            mysite is coming soon        </title>
        <style type="text/css">

            .headerText {
                width: 550px;
                margin-top: 10%;
                margin-right: auto;
                margin-left: auto;
                font-size: 28px;
                font-weight: normal;
                display: block;
                text-align: center;
            }

            .bodyText {
                width: 550px;
                margin-top: 15px;
                margin-right: auto;
                margin-left: auto;
                font-size: 14px;
                font-weight: normal;
                display: block;
                text-align: center;
            }

            body {
                margin-left: 0px;
                margin-top: 0px;
                margin-right: 0px;
                margin-bottom: 0px;
                background-color: #222222;
                color: #FFF;
                font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
            }
        </style>
<script>
  (function(i,s,o,g,r,a,m){i['GoogleAnalyticsObject']=r;i[r]=i[r]||function(){
  (i[r].q=i[r].q||[]).push(arguments)},i[r].l=1*new Date();a=s.createElement(o),
  m=s.getElementsByTagName(o)[0];a.async=1;a.src=g;m.parentNode.insertBefore(a,m)
  })(window,document,'script','//www.google-analytics.com/analytics.js','ga');

  ga('create', 'UA-12345678-1', 'mysite.com');
  ga('send', 'pageview');

</script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <span class="headerText">
            http://www.mysite.com        </span>
        <br/>
        <span class="bodyText">
            is coming soon        </span>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: I assume that "12345678-1" and "mysite.com" are placeholders for this post, and not what you actually have installed on your site?

Comment: @StephenOstermiller Yes, those are the only two things that I modified in the code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You sent me the URL of your site via email.  I visited the site and used Chrome's developer tools to verify that requests are actually being sent to the Google Analytics data collection URL.  There doesn't appear to be anything wrong with your site or your tracking setup.

Here is a [helpful post about this in Google Product Forums](http://productforums.google.com/d/msg/analytics/WlMQzed6wC8/t1-Y2mAYlQUJ):

> The tracking status messages have been 'buggy' for as long as I can remember.
>
> The tracking status check is a separate check done by the system. It doesn't update automatically the moment you install the tracking code
>   It can take a few hours up to 36 hours (and some platforms it can even take up to 72 hours). Sometimes it doesn't update at all even when the code is obviously installed and working and data has begun to appear in your account.
>
> You can do a quick self check of the code (providing you aren't using some method to block your own visits.)  Log into analytics and go to the real time overview in standard reports. Open up your site in another browser tab or window and have a bit of a meander around your site. If your tracking is installed correctly, after 30-60 seconds you should be able to see your own site activity within the real time overview.